# creating zend project with netbeans, how to?

Tags: php, netbeans, zend-framework2

i downloaded zend framework 2.0 and include the `zf.bat` file in the netbeans as well in the Environment Variables

i place the zend framework into my xampp folder for convenience: `C:\xampp\zf\bin\zf.bat`

When i try to register provider in netbeans i get :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Tool\Framework\Client\Console\Console' not found in C:\xampp\zf\bin\zf.php on line 611

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Tool\Framework\Client\Console\Console' not found in C:\xampp\zf\bin\zf.php on line 611
```

any ideas on what might be causing this error?

thanks

edit:

looks like is a 2.0 release bug, because 1.11 works just fine.

also the `Tool` folder is missing from inside `zend` folder. but i was able to find it inside `tools`. but even is i copied it  over it still doesn't work.

there suppose to be a class called `Console` because that is the actual error, and i couldn't find it in all trunk

wired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the downloads from: http://packages.zendframework.com/ do not have everything...

I had the same issue and got what I needed from here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2

Answer (score 4):

Zend Framework 2 is different from Zend framwork 1.11 and the creation of zf.bat no longer available